# Asterisk recording all sound in a call

Tags: asterisk, record, monitor

I have an Asterisk, I want to record all sound(tone, ring, pressing number...) in a call not just the conversation between two endpoints.

Is there any solution for this requirement?

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that

```
Exten => _X.,1,Mixmonitor(filename_here.wav)
exten => _X.,2,Dial(sip/something); or any other processing
```

recording will start after mixmonitor. it will record all.